# Default value for "microtime" column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, default-value

My interest is to store the time with FSP of 6. As I've read, this cannot be achieved with `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` data types. So, I have a `double` field to store the output of the `microtime` function.

Is there anyway I can set (or even write some code to create) a default value for such a field?

I want to use something like `NOW(6)` and get `1442059062.065123` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could format it with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` like below:

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6));
+------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6)) |
+------------------------+
|      1442068528.543100 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

You can find any others date and time functions **[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)**. You could add a `trigger` and if you want a default value for your `decimal(16, 6)` *microtime*, use `BEFORE INSERT` and replace your `NEW.bigintvalue=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6));`.

### Example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `test`.`test1` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `time` DECIMAL(16, 6) NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `test`.`test1_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `test1` FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> SET NEW.time=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6));
    -> END
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> 
mysql> # Adding 1 into id field
mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`test1` (`id`) VALUES ('1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.test1;
+----+-------------------+
| id | time              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | 1442069359.675330 |
+----+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Isn't there anyway of saying `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6))` as the default for the field?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want `DOUBLE`?  Or `DECIMAL(16,6)`?

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6));
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6)) |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|            1442099776 |      1442099776.196746 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Or multiply by 1000000 and use `BIGINT`?

```
SELECT 1000000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6));
+----------------------------------+
| 1000000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6)) |
+----------------------------------+
|          1442099987061904.000000 |
+----------------------------------+
```

(the decimal places will vanish when storing into a BIGINT.)

Comment: Although this is the way I want to store dates (with 6 decimals), @oNare's answer is the one that fits me, because he showed me how to add the `DEFAULT` value definer for my field